# MongoDB query with constraint on sum of attributes

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'd like a MongoDB query that returns records where the sum of certain attributes satisfies a constraint, for instance given the following documents:

```
[
  { _id: 1, q1a: 20, q1b: 50, q1c: 30},
  { _id: 2, q1a: 50, q1b: 30, q1c: 20},
  { _id: 3, q1a: 0, q1b: 0, q1c: 0},
]
```

Id like to run a query that return all and only docs where `(q1a + q1b + q1c) == 100`, which in this example is records 1 and 2 above.

Is there a way to express this in MongoDB without using `$where` and writing the sum as a Javascript function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) along with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/index.html):

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [ 100, { $sum: [ "$q1a", "$q1b", "$q1c" ] } ] } })
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sDgVhk1ZRpC)